# Angular2 Error inline template:1:20 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

first of all let me start by saying I'm fully aware that there are a few similar posts related to this console error.

Normally I would refer to those but I have been using Angular2 from scratch for a total of 5 days and this is the first JS framework that I have ever used so trying to relate my problem to another is proving more difficult. Please bear than in mind before tearing me to shreds!

Now moving on to my problem, I have managed to cobble together a very basic scaffold for a site and I've created several components that I'm basically treating as each "page" of the site (in this case, 'home', 'contact', 'navbar', 'footer'). I have started to try and implement routing so that when the URL = '' you get redirected home, or if you put a specific in, it directs you accordingly.

The problem I'm getting is as soon as the site loads I get this console error: "Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:1:20 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

My search so far has told me that somewhere I've got a recurring function, I tried to eliminate the variables (so far all of my classes contain almost 0 code) but I'm still getting this error.

Here is my app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {ContactComponent} from './contact/contact.component';
// import {ProjectListComponent} from './projectlist/projectlist.component';
// import {ProjectDetailComponent} from './projectdetail/projectdetail.component';
// import {ProjectComponent} from './project/project.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './navbar/navbar.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer/footer.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  // { path: 'project/:id',      component: ProjectDetailComponent },
  // {
  //   path: 'projects',
  //   component: ProjectListComponent,
  //   data: { title: 'Projects List' }
  // },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  // { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    // ProjectListComponent,
    // ProjectDetailComponent,
    // ProjectComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {ContactComponent} from './contact/contact.component';
// import {ProjectListComponent} from './projectlist/projectlist.component';
// import {ProjectDetailComponent} from './projectdetail/projectdetail.component';
// import {ProjectComponent} from './project/project.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './navbar/navbar.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer/footer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

home.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HomeService} from './home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [HomeService]
})

export class HomeComponent {
  private title;

  constructor(homeService: HomeService) {
    this.title = homeService.getContent();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if you need my HTML but here is app.component.html

```html
<navigation></navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

and home.component.html (like I said it's basic at the moment)

```html
<home>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</home>
```

I'm pretty baffled so far, I realise there is alot to take in and I'm trying to follow a couple of online courses (it's not being made easy by the changes from beta, most courses seem to be quite old at the moment).

Anyway I really do appreciate any help you can offer me and I most definitely appreciate you taking the time to help this noob be a little less noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `home.component.html` has a `<home>` tag in it. This cause it to infinitely create new home components which results in your maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Angular is trying to render something like:

```
<home>
    <home>
        <home>
          ...
        </home>
    </home>
</home>
```

Comment: Correct. You should just have the markup that makes up the view of the home component. So `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`

Comment: Thanks for that, I cant believe it was so simple! There's still so much of this that just seems like sorcery haha :)